# Picture disapears when using display: block; but not display: block-inline;

Tags: html, css, django

New to Django & Front-end development. Trying to work through a [treehouse](http://teamtreehouse.com/library/how-to-make-a-website/adding-pages-to-a-website/style-new-pages) tutorial on CSS. It consists of a base template, treehouse.html, and about.html. I'm extending the base template so about.html looks like this:

```
{% extends "treehouse.html" %}


<!-- Change which item in the menubar is selected. -->
{% block menubar %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'basehunters.views.treehouse' %}">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="{% url 'basehunters.views.treehouse_about' %}" class="selected">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
{% endblock %}


<!-- Remove picture gallery from about page -->
{% block picture_gallery %}{% endblock %}


{% block vanity %}
    <section>
      <img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}img/hulk.jpg" alt="Photograph of Nick Petit" class="profile-photo">
      <h3>About</h3>
      <p>Hi, I'm Tyler</p>
    </section>
{% endblock %}
```

When I configure the display property to have the block value, then the picture disappears. However, when the value is inline-block then the picture appears as expected but not in the center as I hoped.

```
.profile-photo{
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 150px;
    margin: 0 auto 30px;
    border-radius: 20px;  
}
```

Do you know why the picture disappears when the display property uses the block value? The treehouse tutorial does not include Django. I'm trying to configure Django as I work through the front end development tutorials. Thank you for your time.

Comment: The property [is `inline-block`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/display), not `block-inline`

Comment: Thanks, I made that change. When I saved the code, it didn't make it so I couldn't see the picture. So still not sure what's going on with 'block'

Comment: Could you try to reproduce the issue in a fiddle (jsfiddle.net) - May be you can figure it out yourself...

Comment: I don't see anything in there that looks like it would work with Django templates?

Comment: Well. You can always create a fiddle with the generated html

Comment: You're right. The issue ended up being how Firefox rendered the page. The solution was to add clear:both; to the .profile-photo selector.